# custom design ui a listview in android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I have a ListView in my project . How I can custom design it according to below picture (between each row and next row must be exist a gap or a space and color each row must be different by background of ListView )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hadis_lsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can show to us what you have tried ?

Comment: You should change the color for each row in the row_layout and for the "gap" or "space" you just need to specify a margin in the row_layout too.

Answer (score 0):

You should give padding to your RelativeLayout or margin to ListView for gaps or space between Listview.

And for background changes make two ListView for bind in recyclerview. Then put a condition on your onBindView to bind specific ListView.